# Print command does not show everything

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to see all the contents of my data, but after I type

```
print "location_country" , df['loan_amount'].describe()
```

The output shown is incomplete. I get a line with "..." That is:

```
Albania           count    1158.000000
                  mean     1466.364421
                  std      1698.249173
                  min       450.000000
                  25%       950.000000
                  50%      1375.000000
                  75%      1900.000000
...
Zambia            mean     2103.071672
                  std      1688.244747
                  min       375.000000
                  25%       550.000000
                  50%      1475.000000
                  75%      3025.000000
                  max      6625.000000

Length: 688, dtype: float64
stats_country
```

I do not know how to make visible all the data that should be printed.

Comment: This presumably is using pandas. That's rather an important distinction.

Comment: because pandas(numpy really but meh) courteously assumes you dont want a million lines spit out ...

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the number of rows shown by default (along with a lot of other options) using [`pd.set_option`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option).  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"country": list(string.ascii_uppercase)*10, "loan_amount": range(260)})
>>> df.groupby("country")["loan_amount"].describe()
```

shows `A`, `B`, then `...`, and then `Y` and `Z`, but

```
>>> pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 1000)
>>> df.groupby("country")["loan_amount"].describe()
```

shows

```
country       
A        count     10.000000
         mean     117.000000
         std       78.718909
         min        0.000000
         25%       58.500000
         50%      117.000000
         75%      175.500000
         max      234.000000
[I'm skipping B through I here, they're really shown]
J        count     10.000000
         mean     126.000000
         std       78.718909
         min        9.000000
         25%       67.500000
         50%      126.000000
         75%      184.500000
         max      243.000000
[same thing, I'm skipping K through Y]
Z        count     10.000000
         mean     142.000000
         std       78.718909
         min       25.000000
         25%       83.500000
         50%      142.000000
         75%      200.500000
         max      259.000000
Length: 208, dtype: float64
```